# What is the best extinguishing agent when wheels catch on fire?

Tags: aircraft-systems, aircraft-maintenance

What extinguishing agent must be used in the event of a fire involving wheels/tires? Why?

Comment: I don't see the other question as a duplicate. The answers there certainly don't address the issues presented here, such as rubber or metal fire.

Answer (score 4):

You can [find some discussion in this thread](http://www.pprune.org/tech-log/462923-extinguishing-aircraft-wheel-brake-fires.html) but what you are looking for is

> **Fire Service manual. Volume 2. Fire Service Operations : aircraft**
>
> **incidents Home Office - London**
>
> **HMSO, 12/99. Crown copyright 1999**
>
> **ISBN 0-11-341192-8; 0113411928**
>
> **5.4.2 Brake and wheel fires** The overheating of brake and wheel assemblies usually follows excessive braking. This can happen on
>   landing when a hydraulic failure reduces the ability of the pilot to
>   utilise control surfaces (flaps) and he feels the aircraft may over
>   run the runway or more often, on an aborted take-off. Quite often
>   tyres will burst or, as the aircraft comes to a standstill, ignite by
>   transference of heat from the brakes. **To avoid metal failure,
>   firefighters attending overheated brake and wheel assemblies should
>   usually refrain from applying water and allow natural cooling. If
>   there is fire however, a fine water fog applied from fore and aft of
>   the undercarriage assembly is generally used.**